# Double Vertical Scroll View in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

hi I have a activity with three vertical linear layout with respective layout_weight with orientation vertical . I have added 10 image to left and right linear layout . Middle layout is empty.

I want to add scroll view in both left and right linear layout , so that if screen is small , then user able to scroll to see all images in linear layout .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutPositionRow"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="8px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".2" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".6" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".2" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
     </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Whether It is possible.

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your scrollable layouts into `ScrollView`s like in this code:

```
 <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight=".2">
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
 <ScrollView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight=".6" android:gravity="center_vertical">
 </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight=".2">
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
 <ScrollView>
```

Here, I used `layout_width` attribute value for all of the elements as **0dp** because of using `layout_weight`. And also if you would like to position elements in your layouts by `center_vertcial` you should use `android:gravity` attribute instead of `android:layout_gravity`. The last one tells the system how to position layouts on their `ScrollView`s.